# boost::spirit , How to get the "value" of a placeholder

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I am trying to build a parser that accept string of the form "/integer/(/integer/)" and produces a std::tuple
Right now i have :

```
qi::rule<string::iterator,std::tuple<int,int>()> parser = 
      (qi::int_ >> '(' >> qi::int_ >> ')')[_val = std::make_tuple(qi::_1,qi::_2)]
```

which doesnt compile because the placeholders qi::_i aren't of the correct types.How to "extract" the underlying  value from a placeholder ?

Answer (score 2):

Erm, you can just use *automatic attribute propagation* (aka. "auto rule"):

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <tuple>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    qi::rule<std::string::iterator,std::tuple<int,int>()> parser;

    parser = 
        (qi::int_ >> '(' >> qi::int_ >> ')')
        ;
}
```

Note the additional header for the adaptation of `std::tuple` to a Fusion sequence.